# Are talcum powder tins more sustainable than the ones that come in plastic boxes?

Tags: plastic, packaging, dry-waste

I was shopping and as a trial, I bought a talcum powder in a tin container instead of the usual ones that comes packaged in a plastic box. The material looks like a tin, although one cannot tell from the image:

[image: Yardley Gold Talcum Power Tin]

Are the tins more sustainable than the plastic boxes ? I did read this [question on tin containers .vs. tetrapak](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/3000/are-tetrapack-tomatos-more-sustainable-than-tinned), though not a direct comparison with plastic.

I watched the famous video clip called [Story of Stuff](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9GorqroigqM) recently and it compounded my question.  If we were to include the total upstream cost of the packaging, it looks like a tin container may be more costly (from an environmental view). That's why I have this question.

If it helps for the context, I live in small Indian town, where there are very few choices for responsible waste disposal, except the local scrap shop, who I hope segregates well. Or, if I submit well-segregated waste, at least he won't mix it with unsegregated ones.

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP, but recent studies have shown health risks of talc. Sadly talc still works better than alternatives like corn starch. Not your question, but just fyi: https://www.canada.ca/en/health-canada/services/chemicals-product-safety/talc.html  https://www.cancer.org/cancer/cancer-causes/talcum-powder-and-cancer.html